# Assign run command for all media files

Tags: file-format, command-line

Currently Totem/Movie Player opens and plays any type of media files, be it audio or video - is there a way to change that run command?

**EDIT**

I am already aware of properties option from right-click's context menu, but as I said, I want to change the run command for **all** items considered to be media files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First Install Ubuntu Tweak from [this site](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/).
- Launch it by searching for it from the dash .
- Go to the  System -> File Type Manager .

[image]

- Select all formats of the category you want by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> .

[image]

- Now click on the edit button and select the application you want to open the formats .

[image]

- Done .

Comment: But of course! I completely forgot about Ubuntu Tweak! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and Ubuntu Tweak is **not** available in the Software Center, you either add PPA or download `.deb` file.

Answer (score 1):

A command to change file associations command style is `mimeopen`. This is an interaction though since it prompts for an answer while showing a list of possible options. Also this requires you to do this for every file association. There is not 1 command to change all media files to 1 application but you can work around this.

The users preferences are stored inside `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. The system wide file associations are stored in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`.

You can display all relations to video with this:

`cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | grep video`

You could use this to add all video references to the local version like so:

`cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | grep video >> ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.  (`~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` probably has not got the right permission to change it so you will need to change it first).

After that you need to change all references in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` to `=totem.desktop` to `={yourprefferedapp}.dekstop`. {yourprefferedapp} could be vlc or any other reference to a video playing utility.

(do not to forget to rest the permissions for `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` (needs to be 755).

Same can be applied to 'audio' or any other file association.

**Even so this still requires your system to have ALL media types present** and I do not believe that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a file -> Properties -> Open With. There you can choose another default application for each media type.

Comment: **ALL** media files.

Comment: @Oxwivi I do not think it is fair to -1 him when you are the one that did not mention this in your post. In chat you also asked for command line and I do not see you mentioning that in your post either. That does not mean Alautik's answer or user17392 answers are wrong.

Comment: @Rinzwind, yes, I might have been unfair about it, but I was a little moody at that moment - I cannot change it since it's already been three hours. And about command line, I did not imply I will not use solutions anything other than commands.